# How to disable Content-Security-Policy my .net wasm app

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly, content-security-policy

I have .net 7 blazor wasm application (client + server) I constantly see errors in my web browser like this : [image: screenshot of error from browser console]

Because of these issues, I probably can't debug my client side application from Visual Studio.
I'm trying to disable CSP or at least relax the restrictions a little if debug mode. But I can't!

I've added this in my index.html to allow everything :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:; connect-src *;">
```

And this in server side (program.cs) to ensure that my client settings are not overriding.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnectionPRD") 
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' not found.");
#if DEBUG
connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnectionDEV") 
    ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'ApplicationDbContextConnection' not found.");
#endif

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<ServerHub>();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "cors",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
            policy.AllowAnyHeader().WithExposedHeaders("*");
        });
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapHub<BlazorWasmApp.Server.Hubs.ServerHub>(BlazorWasmApp.Server.Hubs.ServerHub.HubUrl);
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");


app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
    await next.Invoke();
});

app.Run();
```

But i still have same error.

Comment: Could you provide your Program.cs source code (server side)?

Comment: I've edited my question and provided my entire program.cs file.

Comment: I cant even use blob objects because of CSP 

Refused to load the image 'blob:https://localhost:7299/bbc5ab70-801d-4d52-bf4c-1958a7371e79' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src * data:". Note that '*' matches only URLs with network schemes ('http', 'https', 'ws', 'wss'), or URLs whose scheme matches `self`'s scheme. The scheme 'blob:' must be added explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Content needs to pass all Content Security Policies. Adding another policy can only make the total policy stricter. You need to identify where the original policy is set, try searching for elements from it that you can see in the response header. Then you need to modify it or remove it for development.

Comment: I dont have any meta`s except this ones: 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; img-src * data:; connect-src *;">

Comment: Check the server response headers

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by response headers.

Comment: The http response contains headers. In developer tools you can click on Network, load the page, then click on the various requests in the leftmost column and typically the standard view to the right will be headers, both request and response headers.

Comment: Look at my initial question, In my code is present this lines
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Remove("Content-Security-Policy");
    await next.Invoke();
});

This is effective removes any CSP headers from respond, so I do not have any CSP headers in responses